# Can Nightwatch be used to test Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec, nightwatch.js

A contractor for our startup installed the Selenium-based Nightwatch testing framework, since our stack is React-heavy. But he told me that it could even be used to test our Rails code. A new contractor said, to the contrary, that Nightwatch couldn't do unit tests of our Rails controllers and models (which makes sense to me).

Who is right? Do you suppose the first programmer had in mind just that we would do end-to-end testing (certain inputs lead to certain outputs), and that we need not test the details of the Rails code? Do we, as I suspect and as the new contractor asserts, need RSpec or some other Ruby-based testing framework to handle our Rails code, if we want to be a TDD shop?

Comment: Minitest (the Rails default) and RSpec are testing framewords specifically for Ruby/Rails applications. You may be able to do some testing with Nightwatch but I doubt you could do full coverage testing. My 2 cents is to stick with the tried and true. I've never used Nightwatch though so I'm just putting this as a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can be used to test Rails. But only from the outside (only through the Browser). So no Unit/Controller/View Tests.
You'll need MiniTest or Rspec for those.

My two cents (also see comment by @SteveCarey): Since I prefer to stick with what comes with Rails and use as little external tools as possible:

Have a look at System Tests that have been introduced with Rails 5.1 or, if you are on a older version, see if you can write those tests using Capybara/Integration Tests.

Update:

You can find more details on testing framework here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/testing.html#brief-note-about-minitest

It was Test::Unit and nowadays is Minitest. But the basics are the same so it does not really matter.

Another popular testing framework is RSpec. Which you can use instead of Minitest/TestUnit if you want to. I prefer Minitest but there are pros and cons for both frameworks.

Rails 4.2 came with Unit-tests, Functional/Controller-tests and Integration-tests. The built in thing that resembles Nightwatch the most are Integration-tests: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/testing.html#integration-testing

You can also look at libraries such as Capybara (https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara) which calls itself an Acceptance Test framework. It integrates nicely with TestUnit/Minitest/Rspec.

Comment: Well, we haven't upgraded past Rails 4.2 or whatever it is we're running.

What is the test framework that is built in to Rails called, by the way? I'm reading the Hartl tutorial and I don't see it named as such anywhere.